# Is there a way to redirect where a program looks for Directx files?

Tags: filesystems

I have an application that can't run off of DirectX11 and instead needs DirectX9. It throws a hissy fit when I try to launch it since it can't find d3dx9_43.dll in my sys32 folder.

Normally I would just install the .dll myself but I don't have administrator access. Is there a way I can change where the program looks for directx files?

Comment: If you have access to the application's binary folder, you could try to copy the dll's into it, right next to the application.

Comment: I could have sworn I already tried that. I'm an idiot. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the application's binary folder, you can copy the dll's into it, right next to the application.

Comment: Just for completeness ;)